# what's taking the place of Service Oriented Architecture?

Tags: web-services, architecture

SOA seems to becoming dated, What are the new Architecture patterns taking its place? Where can I get a good tutorial guide on them?

Comment: Don't think in buzzwords; think about specific situations and solutions. (Either way - this is off topic here on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

SOA is not dated, it's just RESTful and JSON now.

SOA != SOAP, SOA != XMLRPC, etc.